# Unable to use Maven dependency in Eclipse RCP application when using Target Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

I have a large Eclipse RCP application with lots of transitive dependencies.

Currently, these are manually copied into the classpath but that's a significant administrative overhead I'd like to avoid, and would instead like to use Maven, as [discussed here](https://xn--lubisoft-0za.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/).

I've created [a simple RCP application](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#generatetemplatewithcontent).

I've created a `target-platform.target`, which imports the RCP dependencies and my Maven dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target includeMode="feature" name="Running Platform">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.edit.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
        </location>
        <location includeDependencyDepth="infinite" includeDependencyScopes="compile" includeSource="true" missingManifest="generate" type="Maven">
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>osh-core</artifactId>
                    <version>5.4.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

I've set this as the `Active Target Platform`, but when I attempt to access the contents of this dependency in my application (e.g. by using `new oshi.SystemInfo.SystemInfo()`), it can't be resolved.

I thought I needed to add it as a plugin in the `manifest.mf`, which worked for other Maven dependencies I tried, but not this one - it doesn't show up in the GUI list of plugins to add.

And if I add a `Require-Bundle` entry for it manually:

`wrapped.com.github.oshi.oshi-core;bundle-version="5.4.0"`

I get:

`Bundle 'wrapped.com.github.oshi.oshi-core' cannot be resolved`

And get a similar if I try:

`com.github.oshi.oshi-core;bundle-version="5.4.0"`

I have a similar scenario with a different library.

`target-platform.target`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target includeMode="feature" name="Running Platform">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.edit.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
        </location>
        <location includeDependencyDepth="infinite" includeDependencyScopes="compile" includeSource="true" missingManifest="generate" type="Maven">
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.xni06</groupId>
                    <artifactId>JCoord</artifactId>
                    <version>24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>jitpack.io</id>
                    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

If I add a `Require-Bundle` entry for it manually:

`wrapped.com.github.xni06.JCoord;bundle-version="24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a"`

I get:

`invalid range "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a": invalid version "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a": non-numeric "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a"`

And when I try:

`wrapped.com.github.xni06.JCoord;bundle-version="0.0.0"`

I get:

`invalid range "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a": invalid version "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a": non-numeric "24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a"`

How can I get these dependencies imported?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `24347197e2364650a6b1cf2cc46d064414edc22a` can be used as version in Maven, but not in Eclipse/OSGi which requires a [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) version schema. Does forking that GitHub repository, tagging the latest commit with e.g. `1.3.1` and using your Fork via jitpack.io of "version" `1.3.1` work?

Comment: @howlger yes, I probably could work around it - but I shouldn't have to? And this still doesn't address my second problem.

Comment: Which problems remain if you do it as I described in my first comment?

Comment: @howlger see my `oshi` example.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Currently, you tell Tycho to download and convert on the fly a JAR specified by a regular Maven dependencies (not from a p2 repository) into an OSGi bundle/Eclipse plugin. This fails because in your case the version is just a weird string (commit hash) and not a semantic version. In contrast to Maven where artifact versions are only used at compile time, in OSGi/Eclipse bundles/plugins can be installed, started, etc. at runtime for which semantic versions are required. So forking and tagging the GitHub repository should work as a workaround, right?